# Scroll fixed div horizontaly while body stays positioned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to create a social website which has a chat sidebar, which is just like Facebook. It has a timeline with posts in one section and a chat sidebar.

I have made the chat `<div>` to be fixed just like Facebook chat.

Now when the total height of elements within the chat sidebar becomes more than the page height, scrollbar appears. When i scroll through it and reach the end of it, if i scroll more, now it scrolls the posts on the timeline.

So what i want to achieve is, to make chat sidebar scroll irrelative to the timeline. to make this crystal clear, i want them to scroll separately, so if i scroll chats and it reaches the bottom, if my pointer is still on the chat sidebar and i scroll nothing should happen.

I prefer to find a way without the use of jQuery. but if its not achievable with css, i would appreciate any help on javascript as well.

Great Example: [Facebook](http://facebook.com)

> Sample from my html

```
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="timeline">

        <div class="contents">
            <div class="header"><p>Timeline</p></div>

            <div class="post-items">
                <div class="post">
                    <div class="avatar">
                        <div class="frame"><img src="blabla.img" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-block">
                        <div class="post-header"><p>Some Header</p></div>
                        <div class="post-contents"><p>Some contents</p></div>
                        <div class="post-footer"><p>Some footer</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar right-sidebar">
        <div class="chat-list">

            <ul class="friends">
                <div class="header"><p>Friends</p></div>
                <li>
                    <a class="chat-item">
                    <div class="avatar">
                        <div class="frame"><img src="blabla.img" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="name">James Hetfield</span>
                    <span class="ic ic-message"></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the code, or an example?

Comment: @user3272243 added html sample, is css needed as well ?

Comment: Everything helps to spot what you are "doing wrong".

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4d95zLyb/3/) this is exactly my problem, try scrolling on the blue or green box up and down, and u will know what i mean. I certainly don't think i'm doing anything wrong, is should be either a css i'm missing or maybe this is a general browser thingy which i would then need to use javascript to overcome it.

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean now... Lemme check if i can find a solution to this.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/9hf1dwhe/ Based on: http://benfrain.com/independent-scrolling-panels-body-scroll-using-just-css/. Plus is all CSS just as you want. \o/

Comment: @user3272243 Thanks alot, i found this as well before i post this question. but the problem as he also states in his blog is the performance and browser support of this method which uses flex box, which both are quiet important on my current project. So i guess i have no other choice than to use javascript for this. anyways, thanks alot for ur research, appreciate it ;)

Comment: No problem at all, well... It's not so bad to use javascript once in a while and also, welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your timeline in the timeline div and chatbar inside chatbar div. Note in the javascript I have overridden the natural behaviour of scrolling. So, when your mouse is over chatbar normal scrolling wouldn't occur.

**Update:** Whenever the mouse is scrolled while the cursor is over the div manually update the scrolltop property.

JSFiddle : [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/bytestorm/hhq1vk0m/1/)

```
<html>
    <head>

        <style type="text/css">
            #body{
                width: 95%;
                margin: auto;
            }
            #timeline{
                width: 75%;
                display: inline-block;
                overflow-y: scroll;
                margin: auto;
            }

            #chatbar{
                position: fixed;
                width: 15%;
                display: inline-block;
                max-height: 100%;
                margin: auto;
                overflow-y: scroll;

            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="body">
            <div id="timeline">

            </div>
            <div id="chatbar" class="scrollable">

            </div>
        </div>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $( '.scrollable' ).bind( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function ( e ) {
                var e0 = e.originalEvent,
                    delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;

                this.scrollTop += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this works great but is there any pure css method to do this ? @Bishal

Comment: @JohnSnow You are welcome... No, you have to override using javascript (jquery)